# Table width does not work in Outlook 2010

Tags: html, css, outlook, newsletter, electronic-direct-mail

I have created a campaign (EDM) for my client and it works well in mobile, tablet and modern browsers like Chrome and Safari on desktop, BUT it does not work in Outlook 2010 on Windows PC. The width of the table extends to the width of the Outlook window so the layout just broke.

(imgs: [when it works in Chrome](http://imgur.com/a/WelpF) / [that's what happens in Outlook 2010](http://imgur.com/a/QOuYV))

Here is the code I use for tables:

```
<table align="center" width="600px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" table-layout="fixed" > <tbody><tr><td style="text-align:left" overflow: "hidden"></td></tr></table>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width and height in each `<TR>` and `<TD>`

Outlooks are awful with rendering email style / tables :(

Comment: Thank you! I've already set the width in all the <table> <td>, so I will definitely try to set width in each <tr> as well. But I set height="auto", is that alright?

Comment: @IreneShih can you provide more code to view? Perhaps add the full table if possible :)

Comment: @IreneShih also----- 

Check this place out for more info on email styles! 

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: another question - for inline css, should I go for width="600px" OR width="600" ? Some experts suggest me to remove px when styling tables for EDM.

Comment: @IreneShih try turning all of your values set to % a fixed value.

So

width="50%" should be width="250px" or whatever you need! 

Hope that helps!

Comment: No no no! You do not need to define a width or height on table rows and cells. And that is invalid HTML. Please do not dish out advice unless you have a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not define widths or heights on tables rows and cells. Especially rows as that is invalid HTML.
Table cells can have widths when a cell is sharing space with another cell and a cell needs to be restricted to a specific width. Cells can have heights but usually you would let the content or image define that and the cell will adhere to the contents dimensions.

You are also missing all of the head information that is required by email clients to correctly render your design. And you hadn't closed your wrapping Table.
I suggest testing on as many devices as possible and investing in an account on Litmus or Email on Acid to test on devices and email clients...